# Does mongodb transactions implement optimistic concurrency by default?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

Hi I am wondering whether mongodb transactions implement optimistic concurrency by default? For example let's say I start a transaction then do some updates in the session and right before I commit an update was made to a document in that transaction seperately. Does that transaction still go through?

I'm thinking if it does not I should read from the database at the documents getting updated before commit but I feel there's a flaw if somehow by some chance the document gets updated before the commit which would compromise data integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this seems like mongodb locks the document once you request to update it in a transaction. If a non-transactional update happens before the commit it will wait until the transaction is commited, aborted or times out then it will update right after the transaction.